# I Can't accept updated apple developer license agreement

Tags: iphone-developer-program

I have this issue."The Apple Developer Program License Agreement has been updated.In order to access certain membership resources, you must accept the latest license agreement.

when I try to accept The Apple Developer Program License Agreement it takes for long time and there is no result. Still I am facing the problem.

[It displays this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYGdU.png)
can any one help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Login to your Apple developer account and accept updated license agreement:

https://developer.apple.com/account

Also you try from some different browser also or clear all history data from current browser.